# Gradle cannot find plugin, Spring boot project initialized using Spring initializer

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Initialized a spring boot 2.5.0 project along with gradle using Spring initializr (Only Spring web was given as dependency).

gradle build/ gradle bootRun always fails with the following error:

```
What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    maven(https://repo.spring.io/milestone)
    maven2(https://repo.spring.io/snapshot)
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'spring-boot'
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Running Windows 10, gradle 6.8.3, running from command line yields same results.  Please help.

EDIT: Can confirm I am not behind a proxy. Also tried temporarily disabling firewall and running, no luck there.

running gradle --debug build resulted in the following

```
2021-03-26T12:28:35.484+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://repo.spring.io:443
2021-03-26T12:28:35.484+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to repo.spring.io/35.241.58.96:443
2021-03-26T12:28:35.484+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Connecting socket to repo.spring.io/35.241.58.96:443 with timeout 30000
2021-03-26T12:28:35.501+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled protocols: [TLSv1.2]
2021-03-26T12:28:35.501+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2021-03-26T12:28:35.501+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] Starting handshake
2021-03-26T12:28:35.519+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-13: Shutdown connection
2021-03-26T12:28:35.520+0530 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Connection discarded
```

end of logs say result success?

```
Received result Success[value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildActionResult@1f9ce3e] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=9948, address=[<some address> port:55586, addresses:[/0.0.0.0]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1616741885172, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=<some uid>,javaHome=<my java home>,daemonRegistryDir=<my gradle dir>,pid=9948,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
```

I thought it could be an issue with the SSL, but I tried using http on the repo links and that didn't work either.

Comment: It is working fine for me (and the dependency it complains about in the output is present right [here](https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin/2.5.0-SNAPSHOT/)). Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Nope, am not behind a proxy. I did notice that the dependency is available on both the milestone and snapshot repositories. I can only imagine some gradle connection issue here, maybe firewall or something.

Comment: have you considered  to reduce the plugin version, the latest version of this plugin  in gradle plugin repo is [2.4.3](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot)

Comment: I have tried using springboot plugin version 2.4.3, issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue really was with SSL, or rather with my cacerts file.

Replacing the plugins block with buildscript provided better logging, including the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

I then found this thread: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/478

To summarize, it says certain builds of OpenJDK don't have cacerts in them by default, for Windows. Sure enough, my cacerts file was only 32 bytes long :)

I have updated my OpenJDK version and things are working fine now. One could also import cacerts from other places. Thanks to everyone that responded to the question.

That being said, the problem would have been discovered sooner if only the plugins block provided better debug logging.